# Difference between a Multi Org v/s Non-multi org setup for mapping multiple MC Business Units to 1 Sales Cloud Org

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I believe with a non-multi org setup, it is possible to map multiple Business Units, i.e, a Parent and a Child MC BU to 1 Salesforce Org. Then, what is the difference between this scenario and a similar scenario with Multi-Org enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a 'non multi-org set up' it is **impossible** to map more than One child BU to a a Salesforce Org. In the absence on Multi-Org, mapping between BU and Sales Cloud instances are **1 to 1**.

This is a special consideration for the sandbox as without multi org, you lose the ability to have a test environment.

For more information, visit here : [Multi-Org Documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/multi_org_account_configuration/)